# Error: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v11.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Cpp.targets" was not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

I am trying to build a Cocos2D-X project on Windows Phone 8. I am being able to run the app successfully on emulator but when I try to run it on device I get the following error:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v11.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Cpp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Has anyone encountered this error before. I am using Visual Studio express 2012. How can i solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you also have Visual Studio (Express) 2013 installed, remove it and only use Visual Studio Express 2012.

See some details here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2862142

I had the exact same issue. I was using Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone together with Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop on the same Windows 8.1 computer. I uninstalled Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop and installed Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop instead, and now I don't have the issue anymore, I successfully ran the application on a real device. So, only use the 2012 version and it should work.

Comment: I do not have VS2013 on my PC.